# HTML mail not being properly displayed in Gmail, Outlook, etc

Tags: html, email, command-line, gmail

I am sending mails from the command prompt as-

`mail -s "$(echo -e "This is the subject\nContent-Type: text/html")" <my-email-id> < ~/Downloads/report-scripts/mail.html`

The file mail.html is a perfectly written HTML file, which when viewed in browser, renders perfectly. However when sent through mail (say to Gmail), some layout issues creep in. See the following images -

Browser Image -

[image]

Mail Image -

[image]

Note the extra `</td>` element.

I understand that email providers don't render HTML mail as it, and add their own styles to it. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is the HTML valid when you send it?  I'm guessing your browser's renderer disregards the error and the mail renderers are exposing it.

Comment: Pretty sure it's valid. I ran the HTML validitator too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

I have resolved the issue and I have an indication of what might be the problem, but I am not sure about it.

**Using mutt instead of mail solved the issue. So the problem is linked to the mailing utility and not the HTML itself.**

**RCA-**

I checked the original mail content. You can do that in Gmail by following the image

[image]

For mutt, the content was as follows -

```
From: <Some email id>
To: <Some email id>
Subject: <Some subject>
Message-ID: <20160218081616.GA6060@<machine description>>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
User-Agent: Mutt/1.5.21 (2010-09-15)
```

and for mail, it was as follows -

```
Subject: <Some subject>
Content-Type: text/html 
To: <some email id>
X-Mailer: mail (GNU Mailutils 2.99.97)
Message-Id: <20160215054331.4C3EA25E27@<machine-description>
Date: Mon, 15 Feb 2016 11:13:31 +0530 (IST)
From: <some email id>
```

I think it has something to do with the headers sent with the mail.